# Database mail messages are being queued but they are never delivered

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

I have database mail configured properly, it has been working all along but then suddenly iam  getting the error below in the description column of the sysmail_event_log view database msdb.

Any idea why i could be getting this error message?

**Bellow is the error.**

```
"The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2014-02-25T08:29:30). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unable to complete command, no storage available)"
```

Comment: [Please have a look at this this may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025419/sending-email-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: @Sakthivel, thanks for the link, however i discovered the server admins had dis-commissioned the SMTP server with out notice and i was referring to a non existent SMTP server IP  address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue was caused by the server admins had dis-commissioning  the SMTP server with out notice and i was referring to a non existent SMTP server IP  address.