# Send automated email

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I want to send automated emails to UserType( requester, assignee ,reviewer,admin) based on an insert and.or update in Database.

EX:

A remainder email send to requester, assignee ,reviewer and admin if the reviewer is not able to review the data in 7 days from the date it is assigned to him/her.

I know I can do this with SQL JOB or with Windows Services. But I ma looking for different way to do this if possible and/or does SSIS provide such functionality?

Answer (score -1):

I think another option is to setup the trigger on insert/update of tables that need to be monitored then then called a stored procedure that use msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to send out email.

You can look at the answer in this post for reference on how to send email using sp_send_dbmail.
[Sending Email in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025419/sending-email-in-sql-server-2008-r2). I hope that helps.